# Android studio building signed APK error on "Type of anim"

Tags: android, build, apk

I trying to build singed apk with Android Studio.

when i press button to create signed apk i get this error :

> Error: Expected resource of type anim [ResourceType]

And this line of my java code show's up

```
LayoutAnimationController lac = new LayoutAnimationController(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Employment.this,
            R.animator.grow_from_bottom), 0.8f); 
    lview.setLayoutAnimation(lac);
```

I do'nt have any problem to create Unsigned apk. just in singed apk.

Please help me.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two different types of animations in Android: [`Animation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html) and [`Animator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html). Likewise, there are two resource folders for each: `res/anim` and `res/animator`.

[`AnimationUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationUtils.html) works with `Animation`, but you're passing it an `Animator`, which is why it's getting upset. You need to give it an `Animation` resource (i.e. from `R.anim`).

Since it'll be important to learn the difference between the two types of animation, here are some resources:

- [More on property animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) (aka `Animator`)
- [More on View animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) (aka `Animation`)
- [Animation resources definition](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)

Comment: then why it's not causing any problem when OP creates unsigned apk?

Comment: thank you so much for your help. my problem solved. i learned from you about "anim" and "animator". but Alex question's is a good question? actually why?

Comment: Honestly, not sure why that's happening, but I don't feel like investigating since 1. it's a coding problem that can be fixed and 2. unsigned APKs aren't particularly useful (they only become useful once signed).